# If $M^n = I$ then $M$ is diagonalisable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Consider a matrix M over complex numbers of size m×m such that $M^n = I$ for some natural number $n$. Then prove or disprove that $M$ is diagonalisable.

My try:

I imitated the proof of projection  linear transformation. That is basis vectors of null space and image space will be Eigen vectors but I am not sure if it is correct way here.

Suppose $M^2 = I$ then consider a vector $x$ in null space. Then $x =M^2x = 0$ so null space will have only $0$.  Then I am not sure if a basis for image space has some Eigen vectors.

I  tried finding counter examples also but not successfully.

please give me some help. Anyother approach also is fine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To community: I am asking help

Comment: I'm sure we have done this somewhere on the site. Hint: Can you show that every vector is a sum of eigenvectors of $M$? If $M^2=I$, then to each $x$ both
$\dfrac12(x+Mx)$ and $\dfrac12(x-Mx)$ are eigenvectors of $M$. In general you need more terms (and $n$th roots of unity).

Comment: If $M^n=I$ then $M$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$ since $M$ is a zero of $X^n-1$ which is a product of linear terms with only simple roots

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/910605/11619). Many proofs on the site rely on the concept of a minimal polynomial and the fact (follows from Jordan canonical form) that if the minimal polynomial has no multiple roots, then the matrix is diagonalizable. In the present case there is a constructible proof also. Looking....

Comment: [Another](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1013429/11619). Leaving this as a link for I'm contemplating writing an answer that does not need Jordan canonical forms.

Comment: To JyrkiLahtonen:I will definitely try the hint(which you have given in your first comment) and generalising to nth power by finding n Eigen vectors.

Comment: @quantum_spin For what it's worth, I wrote the argument as an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1013429/11619) that is, in my opinion, a better duplicate target.